# http-client excluded from spring-rabbit

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am using `http-client` with `spring-rabbit` in **Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE** and it works fine.

In **Spring Boot 2.0.2.RELEASE** `http-client` is excluded from `spring-rabbit` `pom.xml`.

I don't want to manually add `http-client` and keep track of versions between boot versions.

`spring-boot-starter-amqp-1.5.6.RELEASE`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

`spring-boot-starter-amqp-2.0.2.RELEASE`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>http-client</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Why is `http-client` excluded and can I include it without defining version? Version is `2.0.1.RELEASE` but it is not extracted as a property in `spring-rabbit`.

Comment: i think that is replaced by `<dependency>
      <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
      <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>`

Comment: The `amqp-client` is not the same. I am using `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitManagementTemplate` and it has a dependency on the `com.rabbitmq.http.client.Client` so I need `http-client`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Spring AMQP documentation the dependency `com.rabbitmq:http-client` is now optional. Apparently this was changed to allow multiple client implementations.

> When the management plugin is enabled, the RabbitMQ server exposes a
>   REST API  to monitor and configure the broker. A Java Binding for the
>   API is now  provided. The com.rabbitmq.http.client.Client is a
>   standard, immediate and,  therefore, blocking API. It is based on the
>   Spring Web module and its  RestTemplate implementation. On the other
>   hand, the  com.rabbitmq.http.client.ReactorNettyClient is a reactive,
>   non-blocking  implementation based on the Reactor Netty project.
>
> The hop dependency (com.rabbitmq:http-client) is now also optional.

- Client: an immediate and blocking client
- ReactorNettyClient: a reactive and non-blocking client

[See the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#management-rest-api)

If you want to use the standard http-client you can add the dependency. Please that that you don't need to keep track of the correct version yourself. The version is automatically chosen based on your `spring-boot-starter-amqp` version.

```
// Maven
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
  <artifactId>http-client</artifactId>
</dependency>

// Gradle
compile("com.rabbitmq:http-client")
```

You can also refer to the related GitHub project on how to enable a specific client: [rabbitmq/hop](https://github.com/rabbitmq/hop)

Comment: Sorry about that. In my case I noticed the following. The automatic version does work for me when defining the RabbitMQ dependencies in a custom library, including that library and the http-client dependencies in my application side by side. When I moved the http-client dependencies to the library, I needed to set the versions manually. Currently added

`com.rabbitmq:http-client=2.0.1.RELEASE` and 
`io.projectreactor.ipc:reactor-netty=0.7.1.RELEASE`